# Change the paginator links with the angular-ui bootstrap carousel?

Tags: carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using angular-ui bootstrap carousel and would like to change the right and left navigation  links with images.  It seems that within the tpl they are hardcoded with ‹ and ›

Does anyone have any recommendations on changing these to images without changing the actual angular-ui bootstrap files?  I want to keep this in a library and don't want to change it after each version release.

The only solution I had was a hack to make the control of these angle brackets super small in CSS so they couldn't be seen and placed the images.

```
.carousel-control {
  font-size: 1px
}

.carousel-control.left, carousel-control.right {
  background: url(/path/to/[image-here].png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

The goal for the http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ project is to have customizable templates so if you don't like the default markup you can swap it for your own. If you want to change carousel's look and feel I would recommend overriding the default template (https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/template/carousel).

You can easily override individual templates without messing without touching project's deliverables as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17677437/1418796