# AngularStrap Settings for typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have an input, using angular js and bootstrap, which has typeahead enabled...

```
<input id="cob" name="cob" required type="text" ng-model="user.cob.name" typeahead="c.name for c in consts.data.countries">
```

This is all great, but I can not find out how to change the settings used to initialise typeahead. How can I set options for typeahead?

Comment: Looking at the syntax you are using the typeahead directive from http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ and _not_ AngularStrap... GitHub is down atm so can't point you to the docs for supported settings, but which options you are looking for, exactly?

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource thanks for the tip. I want to be able to change arbitrary settings. My current problem is css rules applied to the typeahead DOM element. I want to be able to disable styles applied to DOM node if possible.

Comment: If you want to update styling the best is to override a template as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17660947/1418796 If you change your question to have more details + a plunk I can help more.