# angular js can't display bootstrap modal when relocate to another folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the bootstrap.ui modal and angular as the frontend, and using the node.js as the backend, in the node.js based server, I used /views folder for ejs template and public folder for storing static resources.

```
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');
app.engine('.html', ejs.__express);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

Previously my angular page is in the /public static folder, the modal works fine. but then I moved the angular page to the view folder, the page is loaded fine. but when it comes to the modal, the page can't display the modal, showing error

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Fmodal%2Fwindow.html

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.7/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Fmodal%2Fbackdrop.html
```

So the error is caused by the fact that template/modal/window.html and template/modal/backdrop.html are still in the public folder, that my angular page can't find these file again.

Now even I relocate the template folder from public to views, it still doesn't work, how can I fix this problem

Comment: Does the problem come from the hardwritten `templateUrl` in [modal.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js) (lines 64 & 86)?

Comment: Thanks, glepretre, I just change 'template/modal/window.html' to '/template/modal/window.html', and now it works. if you put it as the solution, I will approve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem comes from the hardwritten `templateUrl` in [modal.js](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js) source code *(see lines 64 & 86)*?

There's a debate about this implementation: [Github PR](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/1156), [Github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/743).

Comment: amazing just I removed / in my templurl and works but Github PR advised the difference ?!! can you plz comment on that ? thank u

Comment: @KickButtowski You will find good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17660947/3049002