# Angular UI bootstrap accordion - replace template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap accordion with templates. I'm wanting to know how I can replace the template that's injected by the accordion directive without modifying the UI library itself? Can I override the injection of the template somehow?

Thanks in advance

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just adding a template after the bootstrap library. From there I was able to do anything I wanted. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you need to override the class that the angular ui library have. In the css files, but not only, you can find a very precise explanation of every class that the accordion uses, if rewrite the class of your interest in another css file, your attribute override the previous one.