# Conditional styling of bootstrap accordion-heading directive

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Any tip on how to set conditional style of angular bootstrap directive *accordion-heading* without doing changes in original .js? Adding *ng-style* or *ng-class* does not have any effect.

NOTE: I want to avoid setting styling on the div within accordion-heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my case by setting ng-class on **accordion-group** directive, which applied conditional styling for each heading.

I also realized that angular bootstrap templates can be customized easily. Follow these links:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#customize-templates
- [Can you override specific templates in AngularUI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap)
- http://codepen.io/p0123n/pen/lvzbx