# Can we enable drag and move on UISelect (Multiple) to sort the list?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Im trying to look up to see if UISelect(multiple) provides a feature to drag move items within the control to sort the list ?

I tried googling for the same and couldn't find much information on this.

Appreciate if you can provide link to some kind of documentation so that i can start from there.

NOTE : I fairly understand how UISelect works.

Comment: No, ui-select does not have this feature.

Comment: Also, sorting on a select's options makes no sense to me.

Comment: I have a need where i  move an item to first from the list selected and make it default.

Comment: So you need to sort the _selected_ values. Got it. Again, no built-in way of doing this.

Comment: Im Sorry if i was not clear in mentioning Selected values , if there is not built in way to do this , any pointers to hack and achieve it ?

Comment: @Sunil Vurity would you mind accepting the answer from `madc` below so that future searchers can find it more easily?

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference: There has been added a `sortable="true"` option in v0.10. However this feature is not yet properly documented, but for further information, see this [github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/209) or `demo-multi-select.html` in the examples folder.

Comment: @Sunil Vurity would you mind accepting this answer so that future searchers can find it more easily?

Answer (score 0):

It uses the `ui-select-match` directive as the "template" inside an `ng-repeat` that generates them.
Unfortunately that `ng-repeat`, unlike `ui-select-choices`'s `repeat` parameter is hardcoded inside `ui-select`'s directive templates.

Look at this template: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/src/select2/match-multiple.tpl.html

In the build version of `ui-select` it's [inlined](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/dist/select.js#L1332) using `$templateCache`, thus you can easily [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap) it with your own version and apply [sorting](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) on that `ng-repeat="$item in $select.selected"`.

You could also integrate something like [ngDraggable](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngDraggable) there.
The main issue here would be CSS though and absolute positioning used.

Comment: there is an extenson for UI-Select2 to perform Drag-Drop  
https://github.com/Taranys/ui-select2-sortable  
Is there a similar extension for UI-Select ?

Comment: Don't know of any. If you can switch to ui-select2 and ui-select2-sortable works then you should.

Comment: I believe UI-Select2 is deprecated ?