# Using Font Awesome in ui.bootstrap.rating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I use Font Awesome in ui.bootstrap.rating?
I found out, that when I add `state-on="'fa-star'" state-off="'fa-star-o'"` to  and changed `class="glyphicon"` to `class="fa"` in ui-bootstrap-tpls it works.
But I guess there is a more custom way to change the class of the icons.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as you are doing with setting `state-off` and `state-on` is their recommended manner. If you are going to have lots of the ratings on a page, I would just create a custom template and over-ride the stock template. [Here is a post custom templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

I had Font Awesome and so didnt want to include Glyphicons.

uib.bootstrap Version: 1.3.3 - 2016-05-22 uses limited Glyphicons, so this is what i added to my css

```
.glyphicon {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.glyphicon-star:before {
  content: "\f005";
}
/**
copied from 
.fa-star:before {
  content: "\f005";
}
*/
.glyphicon-star-empty::before {
  content: "\f006";
}
.glyphicon-chevron-right:before {
  content: "\f054";
}
.glyphicon-chevron-left:before {
  content: "\f053";
}
.glyphicon-chevron-up:before {
  content: "\f077";
}
.glyphicon-chevron-down:before {
  content: "\f078";
}
```

i.e. added css from Font Awesome 4.6.3 to appropriate glyphicon names

Now i dont know if this code will break on version of Font Awesome