# ui bootstrap multiple decorators

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-decorator

Used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap) to update my accordion template.  Now I need to replace another UI bootstrap template for carousel.  Is there a way that I can chain the decorator functions together or should it be done another way?  Also, what if I need to have various versions of the carousel?  What then?

What i have right now obviously isn't working:

```
.config(['$provide', Decorate])

function Decorate($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('accordionGroupDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.templateUrl = '/modules/projects/views/admin/templates/accordian.html';

    return $delegate;
  })
  .decorator('carousel', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.templateUrl = '/modules/projects/views/admin/templates/carousel.html';

    return $delegate;
  })

}
```

Comment: We have a version of ui-bootstrap without templates, with that there is no need of monkey patching it.

Comment: So what happens if I need to have 2 different carousel templates?

Comment: Essential what I need to create is a carousel within a carousel

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you wanted to decorate any of the existing component from configuration phase of angular, you need to append the Component type to its name, like here you are going to decorate `Directive`, so you need to provider the name to decorator as `carouselDirective` instead of just `carousel`.

**Code**

```
.decorator('carouselDirective', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.templateUrl = '/modules/projects/views/admin/templates/carousel.html';

    return $delegate;
})
```