# How do I use a custom month template with Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-datepicker

In the case of Angular Bootstrap UI Datepicker, I am unable to duplicate the technique for overriding Angular Bootstrap UI templates shown at [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RE9AvUwEmKmAzem9mfpI?p=preview), which is cited at SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap).

Here is my attempt:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').config(['$provide', Decorate]);

  function Decorate($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('datepickerDirective', function($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];
      directive.templateUrl = "calendarOverride.tpl.html";
      return $delegate;
    });
  }
```

And here is my attempt in action: [plnkr.co/edit/xNPzXQHsHxomMmBPwOCc?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNPzXQHsHxomMmBPwOCc?p=preview)

Notice that the calendar table does not show!

Thanks,

G