# Overriding AngularJs DatePicker popup to add new title

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The question says it all.

I have hunted high & low and don't see a way, but, before I hack the template I thought that I would ask here.

Just to make it clear - I want to be able to add some text at the top of the datepicker (which is a popup, if that makes any difference) such as "When is your birthday?".

Comment: Which plugin are you using or rather Can you share with us the code that you are currently using?

Comment: just the standard, from Angular BootStrap-UI  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to do this if you follow this topic: [Can you override specific templates in AngularUI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap) but I will just limit to two, one of which is CSS.

**Template overriding:**

[**Plunker Demo**](http://embed.plnkr.co/irYKqYltWopxrPTYm0V1/preview)

The default file for the popup file is `template/datepicker/popup.html`, you just need to copy the contents of the file and append new code to it. The new code then will be wrapped inside `<script id="template/datepicker/popup.html" type="text/ng-template">` [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ascript) and placed within `<head>`

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();
  $scope.maxDate = new Date(2020, 5, 22);

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $scope.status.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

  $scope.status = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
  $scope.events = [{
    date: tomorrow,
    status: 'full'
  }, {
    date: afterTomorrow,
    status: 'partially'
  }];

  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
});

angular.module("template/alert/alert.html", []).run(["$templateCache",
  function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("template/alert/alert.html",
      "      <div class='alert' ng-class='type && \"alert-\" + type'>\n" +
      "          <button ng-show='closeable' type='button' class='close' ng-click='close()'>Close</button>\n" +
      "          <div ng-transclude></div>\n" +
      "      </div>");
  }
]);
```

```css
.popup-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Overriding code -->

  <script id="template/datepicker/popup.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ul class="uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu" dropdown-nested ng-if="isOpen" style="display: block" ng-style="{top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}" ng-keydown="keydown($event)" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
      <!-- Extra code -->

      <div class="popup-header">When is your Birthday?</div>

      <!-- Extra code -->
      <li ng-transclude></li>
      <li ng-if="showButtonBar" style="padding:10px 9px 2px" class="uib-button-bar">
        <span class="btn-group pull-left">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info uib-datepicker-current" ng-click="select('today')" ng-disabled="isDisabled('today')">{{ getText('current') }}</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger uib-clear" ng-click="select(null)">{{ getText('clear') }}</button>
  </span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right uib-close" ng-click="close()">{{ getText('close') }}</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>

  <!-- Overriding code -->
</head>

<body>




  <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">



    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <h4 class="text-center">Date picker Popup</h4>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"
          close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS edit:**

This is a non-standard way but it doesn't disturb your template structure anyway.

[**Plunker Demo**](http://embed.plnkr.co/FK6p4fuJvFr0rEDpbCEn/preview)

`:before` pseudo element in CSS supports `content` property to create text. Since you don't need to add anything other than header text/title, this is a fitting solution. Check the `style.css` file in the Plunkr to edit the text.

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  // Disable weekend selection
  $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
  };

  $scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
  $scope.toggleMin();
  $scope.maxDate = new Date(2020, 5, 22);

  $scope.open = function($event) {
    $scope.status.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
    $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

  $scope.status = {
    opened: false
  };

  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var afterTomorrow = new Date();
  afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
  $scope.events = [{
    date: tomorrow,
    status: 'full'
  }, {
    date: afterTomorrow,
    status: 'partially'
  }];

  $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
    if (mode === 'day') {
      var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
        var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
          return $scope.events[i].status;
        }
      }
    }

    return '';
  };
});
```

```css
.date-picker + .dropdown-menu::before {
  content: "When is your Birthday?";
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: 25%;
}
.date-picker + .dropdown-menu li {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">



    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <h4 class="text-center">Date picker Popup</h4>
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control date-picker" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"
          close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excellent - upvote and answer awarded :-) I will use the CSS solution, which means that I can update the AngularJS component to a new version without having to change any code. Thanks for a truly elegant solution. I wish that I had thought of it. I will certainly remember it for future use elsewhere

Comment: @Manoj Kumar if I add button instead of the text then how can I listen button click event in my controller ?

Comment: Rubab, I have never used AngularJS before. I attempted this for the bounty as it was easier through normal editing. Can you open a new question please? :)