# Overriding bootstrap directive timepicker custom template-url

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-bootstrap

I am trying override bootstrap-tpls for timepicker directive alone, by giving

```
<timepicker template-url="template/timepicker/timepicker.html" ng-model="mytime" ng-change="changed()" hour-step="hstep" minute-step="mstep" show-meridian="ismeridian" arrow-keys="false" name=""></timepicker>
```

my custom template is in correct path:

```
/app 
  /styles
  /scripts
  /template
    /timepicker/timepicker.html
  index.html
```

Its loading the same default bootstrap template.
I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062543/overriding-angularjs-datepicker-popup-to-add-new-title?lq=1) but they added script in the head tag of index.html but i dont want to add in head tag . I want to load the template from seperate folder only, since its useful commonly for pages.

Comment: i think you should give the whole path in template-url

Comment: So just open console and check what it tries to load.

Comment: its using bootstrap template only ... not my custom template