# UI Bootstrap adds <div> around <uib-tabset> directive, breaking CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

When using `<uib-tabset>` included in UI Bootstrap, the directive template surrounds the resulting unordered list with an empty `<div>` element.

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-{{type || 'tabs'}}" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude></ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" 
         ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
         ng-class="{active: tab.active}"
         uib-tab-content-transclude="tab">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is causing my CSS to break since the CSS selectors are as follows.

```
.tabbable-custom > .nav-tabs > li.active {
    ...
}
```

When I use `<uib-tabset>`, this rule isn't picked up because the hierarchy is now

```
.tabbable-custom > div > .nav-tabs > li.active {
    ...
}
```

Can I avoid having to overwrite my entire CSS library to account for this added `<div>`?

**Update:**

Here is the html from my template:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div class="tabbable-custom">
        <uib-tabset>
            <uib-tab ng-repeat="tabData in tabDataArray" heading="{{ tabData.heading }}">
```

and here is the resulting DOM:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div class="tabbable-custom">
        <div class="ng-isolate-scope">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude="">
```

I can remove the `class="ng-isolate-scope"` by disabling debugInfo, but it doesn't make a difference with the CSS.

**Update 2:**
Another solution could be to remove the `<div class="tabbable-custom">` from my template HTML, and add that class to the empty `<div>` that the `<uib-tabset>` directive places. Is this a possibility with UI Bootstrap?

Comment: Can we see the html with the uib-tabset declared? I'm using the tabset and don't have an empty DIV. I have a class of "BLAH" on my div that is the uib-tabset, and then my css says .BLAH ul  and it works fine.

Comment: Hi Scott, I've updated the post with a template vs. DOM comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to accomplish what I needed by overwriting the UI Bootstrap template as explained in this question: [Can you override specific templates in AngularUI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I using [odetocode](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/14/deep-linking-a-tabbed-ui-with-angularjs.aspx) Example, that implements tabset with [angular-ui router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). and in the `DOM` exactly added a `DIV` with `"ng-isolate-scope"` class. I tried to override this block that achieved from ui-bootstrap-tpl.js by removing additional created `div`, and finally It Works.

```
angular.module("template/tabs/tabset.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/tabs/tabset.html",
    "<div>\n" +
    "  <ul class=\"nav nav-{{type || 'tabs'}}\" ng-class=\"{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}\" ng-transclude></ul>\n" +
    "  <div class=\"tab-content\">\n" +
    "    <div class=\"tab-pane\" \n" +
    "         ng-repeat=\"tab in tabs\" \n" +
    "         ng-class=\"{active: tab.active}\"\n" +
    "         uib-tab-content-transclude=\"tab\">\n" +
    "    </div>\n" +
    "  </div>\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

There's another approach. You can also override the `CSS` Styles by changing related styles to this format:

```
.tabbable-custom > .ng-isolate-scope > .nav-tabs
```

the second approach may be seems boring. But you're sure that tabset template remains intact and does not occur conflicts with other tabset pages.